# Resizing image and having it appear next to text in a php search result

Tags: php, html, css, thumbnails

I have a query result page and am trying to shrink the image and have the title appear next to it. Any recommendations?

Thank you!

```
<?php
while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    $query->the_post();

    ?>
    <div style=background-color:#ffffff;text-align:center>
            
        <?php the_post_thumbnail( );?>
    
            <h2 style="font-size:24px"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
        
        
        <span><small><?php the_tags(); ?><br>
        <?php the_date(); ?></small></span>
        
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a styling issue than a PHP issue. So for now it seems best to give you an example.
For the snippet I removed the PHP parts (variables) and replaced it with some HTML elements for a better experience and to make the snippet work. So here you have an HTML structure and associated CSS to make it happen and getting the idea.

```css
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    align-items: top;
    column-gap: 10px;
    margin: 20px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 300px;
    background: #eaeaea;
}
        
.wrapper .thumb {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;

}
.wrapper .thumb img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.wrapper .info > .title {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: black;
}
.wrapper .info > .tags,
.wrapper .info > .date {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="thumb">
    <img src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/lego/1.jpg" alt="Nevin">
  </div>
  <div class="info">
    <h2 class="title">Some Title</h2>
    <p class="tags"><a href="#">#tag1</a> <a href="#">#tag2</a> <a href="#">#tag3</a></p>
    <p class="date">2023-05-05 00:00</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE (comment related):**
For more clarity, I've added an example of how you might end up after re-inserting PHP parts. But keep in mind that I can only roughly guess what the functions return. You will probably have to play around with this, including the CSS part from above.

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="thumb">
    <?php the_post_thumbnail( );?>
  </div>
  <div class="info">
    <h2 class="title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <p class="tags"><?php the_tags(); ?></a></p>
    <p class="date"> <?php the_date(); ?></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Ferris. But I believe I still need the php part, as this is run after a search request. Specifically, I am giving users the ability to search our press releases based on tags to filter to only those that correspond to the tag.

Would your solution work in this environment?

Comment: Oh, i think you missunderstood me. You definitley will need your PHP code. I only removed it because of the snippet. The snippet function here is not able to deal with php. I just wanted to demonstrate that you will need some HTML containers to make it work. And, the solution works, but needs some adjustments (reinserting the php parts and so on).